# Execute .exe file on server side from local desktop

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, web-applications, virtual-machine

I have an web application, which was working on server (virtual client). After Publishing and checking from the client side(Locally), I'm getting error.

code I used:

```
protected void BtnLoadTempTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
    ps.UseShellExecute = false;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"D:\Solutions\TFS_Itsme\DEV\WebSolution\WebService\bin\Debug\WebService.exe");
}
```

Error I got
File not specified

[image]

Comment: Does the .exe exist in that path with that same exact name?

Comment: I doubt your web application has the rights to run an application this way.  Everything about this screams bad design or miss understanding -- can you please explain the use case.

Comment: That code runs on the web server, so the web server needs to have the `WebService.exe` file in the correct path.

Comment: I am with Hogan here. This looks _really_ suspicious. And my IT Guy would crucify me if I were to even only _try_ that.

Comment: It's better to include error messages as text for clearer reference - the screenshot doesn't add any extra info and it's hard to read.

Comment: Basically my need is:
I have a WebService.exe file which I need to execute via program. I wrote above program to execute it and it is successful while running the application locally but when I deploy it to server it is throwing "System can not find the file specified" error in browser. may you someone help on this ?

Comment: @Mounika -- that is not a use case, you already explained all that in the question.  What does the program do?  Why do you need to run it remotely (as op. to on a schedule or via a local trigger).  What EXACTLY are you doing?

Comment: What's stopping you from including the code of WebService.exe in your web application, rather than trying to run it as a separate process?

Comment: You didn't reveal enough details about your web app, so people have to guess what might be wrong. The C# code you shared indicates that you might be working on an ASP.NET WebForms project and try to run a program called `WebService.exe` from a specific file path. **Note that C# code in such projects only execute on the server side, not client/browser side**, so you need to copy this `WebService.exe` program to the specified file path on that IIS server and also grant the application pool identity permissions to read/execute it from there.

Comment: While calling another program from a web app on IIS is not often considered a good design (due to a variety of reasons), you might have your own judgement when choosing this approach. However, a web app on IIS runs in a very special context, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 so the program being called might fail. But anyway you can post a new question if that happens.

Comment: @sbridewell, I added the code of WebService.exe in my web application and it's working perfectly. Many thanks for giving me an input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer you questions by describing a good architecture to perform what you are describing.   This is designed to be used in a secure production environment.

Requirement:
Allow a remote user to start a process on the server to perform some task.
(You may have other requirements, but at this point all you have given is this one requirement.)

Implementation hardware:

- Secure and locked down web server.
- Secure and locked down application server
- Secure and locked down database server (only be connected to via web and application server

Note, you can run more than one of these on the same physical or virtual server but the processes should be run as different service accounts (users) which have rights to only the resources they need to perform their function.

Data Model

- one or more tables which describe the action which needs to take place (for example run example.exe)
- one or more tables which describe pending actions to perform (for example, perform an action described in the action table now or in the future)

Use case / Process flow

1. User connects to website and requests an action be taken (run example.exe) -- this will typically be selected from a list of allowed actions stored in the DB
2. Website updates the pendingactions table to include information about this request (who asked and when it needs to be run)
3. User interaction is done.
4. On the application server (NOT THE WEB SERVER) an agent is checking for actions to perform.  That agent sees it needs to run the program -- it does so.

-> Program has been run.

OK -- you are probably looking at this and saying "why"?  The importance here is creating a secure environment.  The user is never running or using code that runs other code on the server.  The user can only pick from a list of "approved" actions -- they don't enter the name of the program.  When the program is run it is run in a different context, by a different service account, that has different rights.

---

You probably noticed this is VERY different than the implementation design you described.  This is why I made my comment.  No programmer who has a good understanding of secure architecture would ever implement the design you describe.  It is very likely such a design would be hacked easily.

Comment: There are valid cases to run executable from web apps in this way, and security risks can also be managed. So, merely suggesting a better architecture might not answer the actual question.

Comment: @LexLi -- Sure, give me an example of a valid case to run an executable from a web app in this way.  Then explain how the solution justifies the removing the web server hardening that is stopping it from running a local executable directly.  Also, I did give that solution in my comment already -- I said the web server software isn't letting him do it.

Comment: A very common case is to perform file conversion using pandoc, which just needs to call the command line utility on server side. The comments you left are all about "use case", and I don't think they really hit the cause of the error page in any way.

Comment: File conversion?  I think I would implement a web service to perform a file conversion remotely.